# Как отцентрировать background-image не фиксированного размера с сохранением пропорций?

Tags: html, css, img

Есть блок фиксированного размера, надо в его центре поместить картинку, которая его меньше. Картинка может быть разных размеров. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы она была всегда в центре этого блока и у нее была максимальная высота и ширина с сохранением пропорций. Т.е. если у картинки высота или ширина больше некого максимума, то она дальше не растет, а другое измерение делается с сохранением пропорций. В общем, как работает max-height и max-width у img. Можно ли такое провернуть с background-image?

Answer (score 3):

`background-size: contain` даёт необходимый результат

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.d1{
   background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x150);
}
.d2{
   background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/150x250);
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```